# Jackson Json and no such method errors

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to use jackson to serialize and deserialize a POJO. Going from POJO to JSON works perfectly but going the other direction does not.

I have a POJO

```
public class Event {
  private String kind;

  public String getKind() {
    return kind;
  }

  public void setKind(String kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
  }
}
```

and to run and test I run package calendar.model;

```
Event event = new Event();
event.setKind("This is a kind");
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event); 
// RETURNS: "{\"kind\":\"This is a kind\"}"

objectMapper.readValue(json, Event.class);
```

Throws Exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getValueAsString()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:375)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:98)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:308)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2796)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1942)
at calendar.controller.RootController.details(RootController.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
```

I have played with about all I can to get the JSON to POJO to work but it won't.  It does work if I map from JSON to a Map type.

Thanks for the help

### EDIT

here is a grep for jackson in my dependencies

```
± > mvn dependency:tree | grep jackson                                                                                                                       -I- 
[INFO] +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.13.1-beta:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.1.0:compile
```

It looks like there is no other version of jackson except for jackson2.

The full method being run is a spring controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public Event root() throws IOException {
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setKind("This is a kind");
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event);
    // RETURNS: "{\"kind\":\"This is a kind\"}"

    Event mapped = objectMapper.readValue(json, Event.class);
    return mapped;
  }
```

Comment: Your stacktrace indicates that your object is being serialized in a way other than what you showed in your question. Too me it looks like you have a different version of the core Jackson library in your classpath. Please post more representative code, and verify which Jackson JAR's are bundled together with your app.

Comment: @Perception I edited the question, but there is really not more going on then what I gave before, if you can be more specific about what may help maybe I can give more info.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are getting incompatible versions of `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind` - jackson-core 2.0.5 is being pulled in, but I believe at least 2.1.0 is required.

The first line of the exception tells you that it can't find the method `JsonParser.getValueAsString()`, looking at the API docs for [2.0.5](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html), that method indeed does not exist. It looks like it was added in [2.1.0](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html).

So, you'll need to fix the dependencies - most likely by excluding 2.0.5 and including 2.1.0.

Comment: Instead of excluding, you could add a `<dependencyManagement>` section that declares the appropriate versions.  A bit more elegant than excludes.

Comment: Flawless thank you guys, the easiest way was to add jackson-core 2.1.1 as an explicit dependency in my pom, if that is not the best way I let me know.

Comment: If you download the AWS SDK for Java, get the latest version, and then `third-party` folder will contain important jars that you MUST include on your classpath (not just build path).... a little odd.

Comment: @austinbv thank you, when I used the latest version of jackson-core it fixes my problem: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>