# Conflict of Jackson dependencies / Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, jackson

My java class throws this error when deployed on tomcat:

> ```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: 
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getValueAsString()Ljava/lang/String;
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
> ```

When tested locally the class runs perfectly well. I understand that there might be a conflict of Jackson version, but I can't find out.

Here is an extract of my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.skylads.skott.webapp</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Skylads CRM App</name>
    <description>CRM App integrating various features</description>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <artifactId>crm</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>v2-rev98-1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev323-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

App runs on Tomcat 7.0.
Edit: Full `pom.xml` added
Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your whole POM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914728/jackson-json-and-no-such-method-errors

Answer (score 2):

OK guys, i'm out of this nightmare. I used http://jhades.org/ to identify the overlapping jars, went into web-inf and removed old jars that were conflicting and creating the issue.

Maven is very cool but doesn't solve everything, I lost 3hours+ on this issue...

Thanks again for your contribution that were very helpful.

Soufian

Answer (score 0):

As you said on tomcat you are using a different version of jackson-core than in your build.
Find out what you use in maven with  mvn help:effective-pom
Than have a look what you have packaged in your war.
Its also possible,that tomcat uses its own jackson library that makes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided extensive information about your question but I can tell you that version 2.1.0 is the first version to have the [getValueAsString](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html?is-external=true) method. The [version](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.1.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#getValueAsString()) in your pom.xml also does have it. Older versions do not have it and this where your problem is. So according to my experience, this is clearly a problem that you have two jackson-core jar versions running and the class loaders are getting the older version first. You need to do something like:

```
$ find . -name "*jackson*"
```

in your tomcat 7 directory. Find the older version and remove it from your integration. Read the tomcat 7 webpage to know more about classloaders for your tomcat version.