# jackson.databind no such method errors

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson, auth0

I'm using [auth0-java](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-java) client library to interact with [auth0](https://auth0.com/) `v2` service, my codes compile and works fine at my development environment but when I deploy that build in another test environment it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readerFor(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader;
    at com.auth0.json.mgmt.users.UsersPageDeserializer.getArrayElements(UsersPageDeserializer.java:52)
    at com.auth0.json.mgmt.users.UsersPageDeserializer.deserialize(UsersPageDeserializer.java:30)
    at com.auth0.json.mgmt.users.UsersPageDeserializer.deserialize(UsersPageDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3562)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2597)
    at com.auth0.net.CustomRequest.parseResponse(CustomRequest.java:63)
    at com.auth0.net.BaseRequest.execute(BaseRequest.java:37)
    at com.myapp.security.Auth0Service.getUserByEmail(Auth0Service.java:246)
    at com.myapp.security.Auth0Service.checkForExsistingAuth0Account(Auth0Service.java:266)
    at com.myapp.security.AdminUILayout.lambda$launchProgressUpdater$0(AdminUILayout.java:293)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've already gone through several stackover flow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914728/jackson-json-and-no-such-method-errors)  and tried by cleaning `.m2/repository/com/fasterxml` folder of that test environment, but cloudn't solve the no such method error 
here is my pom file and related codes are given below:

**code**

```
public User getUserByEmail(String email){
        UserFilter filter = new UserFilter();
        filter.withQuery(email);
        Request<UsersPage> request = mgmt.users().list(filter);
        try {
            UsersPage response = request.execute();
            for (User u:response.getItems()) {
                if (u.getEmail().equals(email)) {
                    return u;
                }
            }
        } catch (APIException exception) {
            // api error
            System.out.println("APIException:::::"+exception.getDescription());
        } catch (Auth0Exception exception) {
            // request error
             System.out.println("Auth0Exception:::::"+exception.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Other exception:::::"+ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.8.5</jackson.version>
  </properties>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>auth0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Update**
I've moved those jackson dependencies into `<dependencyManagement>` section of my `pom.xml` file,

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

according to [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) ,no matter which version of library `jackson-core` is requested by a dependency, version `${jackson.version}` will always be used, still my codes works in local ,but in that test server 
 the the exception remains same, even if I deploy my war file in that test server code throws the same exception.

Comment: What test server and version are you using?

Comment: here is my test server configs :  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64) , Glassfish 4.1.1 and openjdk 9

Comment: Well, I am using WildFly most of the time. But I can find a lot of articles about jackson and glassfish 4 issues http://blog.mikeski.net/blog_post/449

Comment: @MartijnBurger yes, we are moving from glassfish too and planning to use [Payara](http://www.payara.fish/) from now on , that test server will also be updated , I'll update this question if the issue solves after using Payara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally solved the issue , I found that `glassfish 4.1.1` has a very old version 2.3.2 of `jackson-core` `jackson-annotation` and `jackson-databind`, so we decided to use [Payara](https://github.com/payara/Payara) server that uses fairly latest version of jackson [jackson 2.8.5](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/nucleus/pom.xml#L210) and tested the no such method error is solved, the code works fine in that Payara server

**Update:**
`glassfish` version `5.0` uses updated version `jackson 2.8.9` , I think using that will solve this issue too

Comment: @thanhdung0312  Use`glassfish` version `5.0` , that uses updated version `jackson 2.8.9` , I think upding glassfish will solve your issue https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/releases/tag/5.0-b23

Answer (score 4):

most likely you have compiled your code against a different version of the class, than the one you are using when running it.

Please make sure that on the environment where you run the code there is no any other version of `jackson-databind` dependency on your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm checking  the entire dependency graph to exclude  any other older version

Comment: I think in the pom dependency graph you will not have any problem, because if execution of `mvn clean install` succeeds the maven compile phase then that means that even if there are transitive dependencies the dependency resolution has chosen the right version where the needed method exists and put that version into the built artifact. I think the problem is in the environment where you try to run the built artifact, possibly in classpath there is also another version of the same jar.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of your other artifacts depends on different version of databind. You can try to exlude it explicitly from each of them to guess

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check version.

Screenshot:
[image: Versions screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For me, I encountered the same exception due to lower version of jackson-databind:

**From:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Changed to:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I just update my pom.xml file with higher version of jackson-databind. 
Then `right-click Project` `-->` `Update Maven Project` and the exception is resolved.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!-- faster JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: The issue is already solved and we found the reason behind the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/44201736/1298308 ,  anyway welcome to stackoverflow